# omniauth request email through twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Is this possible with twitter api? like in facebook i can request more information, can i request the user email through twitter? how?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no twitter doesn't give out the email using the API

Comment: As far as I know in some cases they do, but you have to get special permission.

Comment: That sucks that they don't give out the email address. I use a person's email as a unique field when creating a User in my Rails app. I guess once I authenticate through Twitter I'll have to ask the User to input their email address.